# proving that a function is convex

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose that $f(x)=\frac{1}{k}|x|^k$ where $k>1$ and $k<\infty$. $x$ here is in $\mathbb{R^n}. $ Is $f$ convex? I am trying to use the definition of convexity but it seems like I would need some sort of a generalized form for the triangle inequality. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

$f((1-t)x+ty)=\frac{1}{k}|(1-t)x+ty|^{k}\le\frac{1}{k}((1-t)|x|+t|y|)^{k}\le\frac{1}{k}((1-t)|x|^{k}+t|y|^{k})=(1-t)\frac{1}{k}|x|^{k}+t\frac{1}{k}|y|^{k}=(1-t)f(x)+tf(y)$

where I have used convexity of $x\mapsto x^{k}$ for $k>1$. So $f$ is convex.

Answer (score 0):

The function is convex. In this case the function is actually differentiable, and you can convince yourself that the second derivative is

$ (k-1) |x|^{k-2}$

(check the point $x=0$ separately), using the fact that the derivative of $|x|$ is $x/|x|$.

Since $k>1$, the second derivative is always nonnegative, so the function is convex.